# Display 2 decimal point on laravel chart

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, double

I want to display 2 decimal point for each of the variable that I declare in the controller

```
private $dailyCapital=0;
private $dailySale=0;
private $dailyProfit;
```

So I try to put double in front of each `$this`

```
(double)$this->dailySale += (double)$sale->price;
(double)$this->dailyCapital += (double)($item->buying_price * $sale->quantity);
(double)$this->dailyProfit = (double)$this->dailySale - (double)$this->dailyCapital;
```

After I sent it to `view`,

```
->dataset('Sales by Day', 'doughnut', [$this->dailyCapital, $this->dailySale, $this->dailyProfit])
```

all three are not returning 2 decimal point.

Comment: what are the initial value and returning values ?

Comment: I have initiate the variable to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [number_format()](https://www.php.net/number_format):

```php
(double)$this->dailySale = number_format((double)$sale->price, 2, '.', '');
(double)$this->dailyCapital = number_format((double)($item->buying_price * $sale->quantity), 2, '.', '');
(double)$this->dailyProfit = number_format((double)$this->dailySale - (double)$this->dailyCapital, 2, '.', '');
```

Also, unless your `$this->dailySale`, `$this->dailyCapital`, etc., variables were assigned a numeric value after their declaration, you should use `=` and not `+=` as there is no initial numeric value for it to be added some value.

Comment: I have just initiate 0 to `dailySale` and `dailyCapital`. I try your code and only `dailyProfit` shows 2 decimal point

Comment: It should be work. number_format() is the way to format your output.